# Adding functionality to already existing function (C#, C++)

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

Is there a way in C# to extend a function like following ?

```
void foo()
{
    // function body, instructions

    return;
}
```

and then somewhere else in the code

```
foo += (x) => { // some functionality }
```

Which in practice would add the lambda functionality to be fired at the end of a `foo()` execution.

- What would be the name and the internal details of such mechanism ?
- Is something of this nature possible in C++?

Comment: You can have a list of functions and call them in order and add to that list. But `C++` is a compiled language, you can't edit the actual functions at run-time.

Comment: Isn't C# a compiled language as well?

Comment: But C# is ALSO a compiled language @Galik

Comment: For classes, I can think of inheritance, but otherwise, I am out of ideas.

Comment: You could always create a separate method and just call it from the first method or function. There is even creating overloaded functions.

Comment: Inheritance, yes, but what this achieves is that I can have a baseline function for a multitude of objects and then just append that function by a lambda. It's writing X different small lambdas versus creating X different child classes and X different overloads.

Comment: @V0ldek Overloading is the only way, without creating seperate differently named methods.

Comment: do you really want them to have the same name? why?

Comment: My primary question is still how is something like that called, however. I'd like to find this in C# documentation, but I have no idea for what to look.

Comment: Are you sure  what you wrote compiled ? Maybe you missed the real foo declaration that was a delegate ? Could you provide a minimal and complete example. Which version of C# is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example won't compile with the message :

```
error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is a 'method group'
```

It's not possible to do stuff like that. What you saw was probably [operator += for events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx). Here's an [example with a lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

**Regarding C++**

It's not possible to add a call to the end of a different function (the same as for C#). But you can implement events and overload operator += for your events to accept pointers to functions.

Comment: Could you tell me more implementation of this in C++?

Comment: It's too much to answer in the comment. Google `operator overloading c++`, `calling function by pointer c++`, and then `delegates c++`.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a possibility just to show you that a one minute trial can give you an insight. But as Kirill Daybov mentioned in one of his comment I would encourage you to google *delegate c++*, you will find articles with much stronger technical hints

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>  //c++11

using namespace std;

//For exercice only, C++11 required
template<typename U> class naive_delegate
{
    list<function<void(U)>>_list;

    public:
    naive_delegate<U> & operator+= (function<void(U)> && fref)
    { _list.push_back(fref); return *this;}
    void operator()(U && input_param)
    {
        if (_list.empty() )
            cout << "Nothing to do for call of delegate with param " << input_param << endl;
        else
            for ( const auto & elem : _list)
                elem(input_param);
    }
};
void anwser(int i)     { cout << "The answer is " << i << endl;     }

int main()
{
    naive_delegate<int> ndel;

    ndel(1);

    ndel += [](int i) { cout << "What is the answer ? " << endl; };
    ndel += anwser;

    ndel(42);

    return 0;
}
```

The results are

```
Nothing to do for call of delegate with param 1
What is the answer ?
The answer is 42
```

Note that among others, I am not able to treat removal (-=) ...